# Open multiple URL's from a list in new tabs and get the title of each of them

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open multiple websites from a list in new tabs and get the title of each page.
It works properly when all the websites are up and running..If incase the website is down, that tab is being replaced by the next url in the list.. I want to have that page open even if the page is not working and next url in the list to be opened in the next tab..

This is the code which i m trying :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(
    "C:\\Users\\vbred\\Desktop\\Selenium with python\\Selenium\\chrome\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
pages = ['https://www.facebook.com/', 'https://www.commbank.com.au/','https://www.commbank.com'
         'https://chercher.tech/python/windows-selenium-python']

for p in range(len(pages)):
    try:
        driver.get(pages[p])
        if p!=len(pages)-1:
            driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
            windows = driver.window_handles
            driver.switch_to.window(windows[-1])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

for p in range(len(pages)):
    if p != len(pages):
        childwindow = driver.window_handles
        driver.switch_to.window(childwindow[p])
        print(driver.title)
```

EXPECTED :
All the 4 urls to be opened in different tabs , even if the the third url is not working..

ACTUAL :
First 2 urls are opened in different tabs, but as the third url is not working , in the third tab 4th url is being opened and i dont see the not working url at all

Answer (score 0):

There should be a comma in your 'pages' list (at the end of the 3rd item). I am not sure if it is a typo or you just miss it in your code.
BTW, I prefer open a new tab before the driver gets urls, which means:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
windows = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(windows[-1])
driver.get(pages[p])
```

Imaginition:

1. Open the new blank tab.
2. Get the windows ID.
3. Switch to it.
4. Go to the website by driver.get().
5. Loop until ends.

Maybe you can have a try. Good luck!